# How to return the value of a JSP select box in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm sending to my JSP a `Map<String entityDescription, Entity entity>` to populate a `<form:select>` that's defined as:

```
<form:form id="form" modelAttribute="pojo" action="create" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="ftpConnection">FTP Connection: </label>
        <form:select path="ftpConnection">
            <form:options  items="${ftpList}" itemLabel="description" />
        </form:select>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

The DTO has the FTPConnection ftpConnection field that should receive the ftpConnection defined on the path property of the `<form:select>` element.

The POST method is, roughly, defined as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/parameter/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createPost(@ModelAttribute("pojo") ParameterPojo pojo, ModelMap model, Errors errors) throws IOException, Exception {
    // validate entities
    // save what has to be saved
    return "where it has to go";
}
```

The FtpConnection bean for this instance is a very simple POJO, defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ftp")
public class FtpConnection extends BasePojo {

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;

    @Column(name = "port")
    private String port;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The DTO called ParameterPojo is another very simple POJO:

```
public static class ParameterPojo {

    private String id;

    private String description;

    private String agentId;

    private FtpConnection ftpConnection;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The only output I get is at the browser, like the image bellow.

[image]

No console output.

How can I work this out?

Comment: Where is pojo? If spring can't find it, then 400 bad request will be returned.

Comment: It's sent on the GET method, declared as modelAttribute in the form. The issue is with the lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I had write a small poc for you this works for me.

the DTO are the same

I don't know if you developed the custom converter for the FtpConnection bean, I assumed of yess but if you don't implements this waas the cause of your 400 error becouse spring when you submit the form don't know as converter the bean in a way for submit the info for this propouse I developed such confverter:

```
public class FtpToStringConverter implements Converter<FtpConnection, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(FtpConnection ftpConnection) {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ftpConnection);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "{}";
        }
    }
}

public class StringToFtpConverter implements Converter<String, FtpConnection> {
    @Override
    public FtpConnection convert(String s) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(new StringReader(s),FtpConnection.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

then I register the custom converter in this way

```
@Component
public class MyDefaultConversionService extends DefaultConversionService {


    @Override
    public void addConverter(Converter<?, ?> converter) {
        super.addConverter(converter);

        super.addConverter(new StringToFtpConverter());
        super.addConverter(new FtpToStringConverter());
    }
}

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="myDefaultConversionService"/>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

then I implemented a simpel controller like this

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        List<FtpConnection> ftpConnections = new ArrayList<FtpConnection>();
        FtpConnection ftpConnection = new FtpConnection();
        ftpConnection.setUrl("url1");
        ftpConnection.setPort("22");
        ftpConnection.setUsername("user1");
        ftpConnection.setPassword("pass1");
        ftpConnection.setDescription("desc1");

        ftpConnections.add(ftpConnection);

        ftpConnection = new FtpConnection();
        ftpConnection.setUrl("url1");
        ftpConnection.setPort("21");
        ftpConnection.setUsername("user2");
        ftpConnection.setPassword("pass2");
        ftpConnection.setDescription("desc2");

        ftpConnections.add(ftpConnection);
        model.addAttribute("ftpList", ftpConnections);

        model.addAttribute("pojo",new ParamiterPojo());

        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/paramiter/create" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(@ModelAttribute("pojo") ParamiterPojo paramiterPojo, ModelMap modelMap, Errors errors){
        System.out.println(paramiterPojo);

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

this is the my hello.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>

<form:form modelAttribute="pojo" method="post" action="paramiter/create">
    <div>
        <form:select path="ftpConnection">
            <form:options items="${ftpList}" itemLabel="description" />
        </form:select>
    </div>
    <button> Submit</button>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course this is a very simpel sampel and you consider this as a poc.

resuming the problem that I find in your code was:

1. the absence of converter
2. the wrong action in the jsp

I hope that this quite detailed description of my solution was fine grained enough.

Comment: I see now the problem was not having a converter. I added a `private String ftpDescription` property and its getter and setter to my DTO and am using that along with a `findByDescription(String description` and all is working fine now. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: of nothing was a pleasure to be able to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to include pojo if you want to use the annotations like you state.

```
<form:form commandName="pojo" action="" methon="post">
      <form:options  items="${ftpList}" itemLabel="description" />
</form:form>
```

Comment: I forgot to put the <form:form> definition on the original question. Now edited.

Comment: so you have a field in your pojo called ftpConnection

Comment: yes and yes, the issue is passing the selected value from the list to the POST method

Comment: please post the code for your FTPConnection bean. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since that your controller react to the post at parameter/create url in your `<form:form> .... </form:form>` section the action attribute should be parameter/create and not create

Comment: thanks for your input, but this suggestion returned a HTTP error 404.